# c++ multiple children classes - inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have following  c++ class inheritance structure.

```
Car -> personal -> 2 seats
                -> 5 seats -> Peugot307
    -> lory
```

Base class Car has protected variable 
height, width and some methods, e.g. set_values(), which is pure virtual function.

Let's say, something as:

```
class Car 
{
    protected: 
        int width, height;
    public:
        virtual bool set_values(int &, int &) = 0 ; 


};

class Personal : public Car 
{
    public: 
        virtual bool set_values(const int & h, const int & w) override
        {
            this->height = h;
            this->width = w; 
        }


};

class seats2 : public Personal 
{

// some class spec things

};


void main()
{
    seats2 car1; 
    car1.set_values(2, 10); 
}
```

While compiling, I always get error, that 2seats class doesn't have variables weight and height. 
How to overcome such a problem?

Comment: Probably you have a `non public inheritance`.

Comment: May the upvoter explain please? How is this question _"showing research efforts, useful and clear"_??

Comment: It surprises me that the error is what you say it is. The error you should see, afaik, is because you cannot call car1.set_values, because set_values is protected. Can you paste the actual compiler error? Also, try making set_values public.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I have already fixed an example. Error says following: 7:19: error: no member named 'width_' in "file.hpp"

Comment: Your code compiles for me when I add const to the base function argument type.

Comment: @bla_bla_bla and yet somehow, nowhere in your code is there any reference to anything named `width_`. so the code you are showing is not the code that you are compiling, making the thread a waste of our time. e.g. `// some class spec things` what the heck are "class spec things"? post **all** the code, not just what you incorrectly think is relevant. i am voting to close for not including the actual code to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, the inheritance structure you're describing isn't multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance is when a single class inherits from multiple parents, not when a class has multiple children.

It is simply not possible to access members of the 5 seats class in a method overridden by the Personal class. Bear in mind that this overridden method will need to work for all instances of the class and some of them might not even have the members defined by the 5 seats class (for example, instances of the 3 seats class).

If you want to do something special for the `check_validity` method that looks at members of the 5 seats class, I think it would make the most sense just to override the method again in the 5 seats class. You can still chain up to the parent method to reuse the code from the Personal class. For example:

```
class FiveSeats : public Personal {
private:
        int extra_data;
public:
        virtual bool check_validity();
};

bool FiveSeats::check_validity()
{
        // First chain up to the parent method
        if (!Personal::check_validity())
                return false;

        // Check something that is specific to the FiveSeats class
        if (extra_data != 42)
                return false;

        return true;
};
```

Comment: The OP completely changed the question in an edit while I was writing this, so my answer doesn't make much sense any more :/

Comment: Feel free to flag it as off-topic for not including any code to begin with, still not including the actual code being compiled - or not _all_ of it - and continually making edits that change substantial things and hence cast doubt on whether we should assume any accuracy in _any_ of the revisions. Questions asking for solutions without providing an unambiguous, replicable statement of the problem are not useful for anyone and just waste their time, as you have found out by writing this.

Answer (score 0):

From the original problem description, it sounds like `Personal` could be implicitly privately inheriting `Car`. Here's some code that's probably close to what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car {
public:
  virtual bool check_validity() = 0;
protected:
  string id;
};

class Personal : public Car {
public:
  Personal() {
    this->id = "personal_id";
  }

  bool check_validity() override {
    cout << this->id << endl;
    return false;
  }
};

class FiveSeats : Personal {
public:
  FiveSeats() {
    this->id = "fiveSeats_id";
  }

  void test_function() {
    cout << this->id << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Personal p;
  p.check_validity();

  FiveSeats f;
  f.test_function();

  return 0;
}
```